# Using isDirty in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm using the `isDirty()` method in my controller to check if any field is changed. Then I am saving the old data of a field and the new data in a `table`. The code is working fine; however, how can I `optimize` this code?

By using the below code, I will have to write each field name again and again. If `request->all()` has 20 fields, but I want to check six fields if they are modified, how can I pass only `6 fields` in the below code, without repeating?

**Controller**

```php
if ($teacher->isDirty('field1')) {
    $new_data = $teacher->field1;
    $old_data = $teacher->getOriginal('field1');

    DB::table('teacher_logs')->insert(
        [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'teacher_id' => $teacher->id,
            'old_value' => $old_data,
            'new_value' => $new_data,
            'column_changed' => "First Name",
        ]);
}
```

Comment: `getDirty()` will give you an array of what is dirty ...iterate through that  ... how does `field1` relate to `First Name`?

Comment: getDirty will give anything modified,but i want to keep check on 6 fields only and then save them.

Comment: so then filter it to so it can only include what you have predefined for your list

Comment: then how insert would work, saving in log table, i will have to repeat 6 fields in insert? with old value and new value?

Comment: repeat what 6 fields in insert? ... i really can not understand what you are talking about

Comment: as mentioned in my code, if you check i have used, DB::table('teacher_logs')->insert; to save field 1, old value and new value in teacher_log table. what if i have 6 fields?

Comment: please suggest me if there's better way to insert old and new values in a log table.

Comment: i will make an example for you :)

Comment: Thankyou, i have found solution, i have posted as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a list of what fields you want to be checking for then you can loop through the dirty fields and build your insert records.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

...

$fields = [
    'field1' => 'First Name',
    'field2' => '...',
    ...
];

$dirtied = Arr::only($teacher->getDirty(), array_keys($fields));

$inserts = [];

foreach ($dirtied as $key => $value) {
    $inserts[] = [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'teacher_id' => $teacher->id,
        'old_value' => $teacher->getOriginal($key),
        'new_value' => $value,
        'column_changed' => $fields[$key];
    ];
}

DB::table(...)->insert($inserts);
```

Comment: Thank you, how about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

i tried following code after getting idea by lagbox in comments, and i have found solution to my problem.

```
    $dirty = $teacher->getDirty('field1','field2','field3');
    foreach ($dirty as $field => $newdata)
    {
        $olddata = $teacher->getOriginal($field);
        if ($olddata != $newdata)
        {
            DB::table('teacher_logs')->insert(
                ['user_id' => $user->id,
                    'teacher_id' => $teacher->id,
                    'old_value' => $olddata,
                    'new_value' => $newdata,
                    'column_changed' => "changed",
                ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is pretty much what you need to be doing :) only 2 things: 1) `getDirty` doesnt use any arguments, it checks all the attributes and returns any that are dirty, so you will get more than your limited list. 2) you can skip checking `$olddata != $newdata` as `getDirty` only returns fields that fail an equivalency check (they are different than the original value)